# Cannot import module from partially initialized module

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, azure-functions

I am writing an Azure Function where I have two files. First file `helperfunc_postapi` contains some functions which return a value and the second one is calling the functions in first file. I am cythonizing (encrypting using cython package) the first file so that its contents are not visible to others.

The first file contains code like this and has file name `helperfunc_postapi.py`-

```
import azure.functions as func
def function(a):
     return a
```

This file is cythonized.

The second file contains code like this and has name `main.py`-

```
import . from helperfunc_postapi
def test():
    helperfunc_postapi.function('2')
print(test())
```

while running the second file, the ideal output before cythonization is `2` which is correct. But after we are cythonizing the file, we are getting an error that `cannot import name helperfunc_postapi from partially initiatlized module.`

[image]

In second file, we are even trying to use the `import function from helperfunc_postapi` instead of `import . from helperfunc_postapi` but then we are getting an error that `no module name helperfunc_postapi`.

We have tried everything but there is a circular import error or partially initialized module error and we are not able to debug it.

Answer (score 1):

I tried the below code in my Timer Trigger and the helperfunc_postapi was installed successfully when I imported it in main.py as well as init.py of my Timer Trigger:-

**My init.py :-**

I modified the default Azure Functions Timer trigger code below:-

```py
import datetime
import logging

import azure.functions as func

# import importlib
import os
import sys

sys.path.append(os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'TimerTrigger1')))
# helperfunc_postapi = importlib.import_module('helperfunc_postapi')

from .helperfunc_postapi import function

def test():
    result = function('2')
    return result

print(test())



def main(mytimer: func.TimerRequest) -> None:
    utc_timestamp = datetime.datetime.utcnow().replace(
        tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc).isoformat()

    if mytimer.past_due:
        logging.info('The timer is past due!')

    logging.info('Python timer trigger function ran at %s', utc_timestamp)
```

I used this line `sys.path.append(os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'TimerTrigger1')))` and added my TimerTrigger1 function folder name

**My helperfunc_postapi.py:-**

```py
import azure.functions as func

def function(a):
     return a
```

**My main.py:-**

```py
import importlib

helperfunc_postapi = importlib.import_module('helperfunc_postapi')

from helperfunc_postapi import function


def test():
    result = function('2')
    return result

print(test())
```

In main.py, I used

```py
helperfunc_postapi = importlib.import_module('helperfunc_postapi')

from helperfunc_postapi import function
```

**Output:-**

[image]

**My requirements.txt:-**

No need to add the helperfunc_postapi in requirements.txt as that is not a package.

```
azure-functions
```

Deployed the function in Function app and it was successful, Refer below:-

I used below commands from these [**MSDocument1**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/authenticate-azure-cli) and [**MSDocument2**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-core-tools-reference?tabs=v2#func-azure-functionapp-publish)

```bash
az login
az account set --subscription "Subscription-name"
func azure functionapp publish siliconfunc4109
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have one doubt, the function in main.py is same as written in init.py. So, if I have only the `helperfunc_postapi.py` file and `init.py`, then modules imported in `main.py` should be written in `init.py`?

Comment: Yes, that's correct for function to work you need to import the modules and code from main.py to init.py. As init.py is the one that triggers the function. Ideally you can keep main.py and init.py both but for Function to work you need to implement your function logic in init.py.